# EKF implementation on odometry/IMU

Tags: imu, ekf, simulation, odometry

I am applying Extended Kalman Filter for a mobile robot with IMU and odometry data. I am running simulation currently. However, I don't have suitable data for odo/IMU measurements to use. Where can I find those information?

Answer (score 1):

Try this dataset, [Localization and Mapping Dataset](http://asrl.utias.utoronto.ca/datasets/mrclam/index.html). It will be helpful for your problem.

Comment: Thanks but I need the data for IMU(which measures three angular velocities and three forces) and odometry which uses wheel data to calculate two velocities , Do you think you can help me with that?

Comment: No idea. I am working on this dataset. So I refer this.

Comment: IMU is very unlikely to produce force output ... Typically IMU reading are 3 angular velocity from gyroscopes and 3 linear accelerations from accelerometers.

Comment: This is a bit of a link only answer. If the link dies then your answer will not be much use.